# Azure Devops deploy django application to Linux Azure App Service

Tags: django, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

**Before deploying to Linux App Service check status of the Virtual Network at present this is in PREVIEW and we were unable to, easily, connect back into our internal network. There is a work around for Docker deployment but you loose most of the benefits of the standard App service :-(**

Like many AzureDevops tasks this should be easy, but is turning into masochistic nightmare of re-reading the same copied and pasted tutorial examples.

Following the VSCode tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux everything works beautifully and I can see in the output the virtual antenv being created and configured.

However, it's taken a long time to get away from the right-click -> publish habit and to start using AzureDevops as our pipeline, I'm very uneasy nowadays about publishing from my local repo and dev machine.

Trying to get the same working deployment in AzureDevops has thus far not proven particularly easy. The closest help I can find is in this article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops#create-and-run-an-initial-pipeline where if followed through results in the contents of the .zip folder being deployed to \wwwroot folder correctly but the install process not completing by creating a VEnv and installing from the requirements.txt.

**Is it simply the case that this only works from a GitHub repo and not from an Azure Repo?**

Comment: no, its not the case. where your sources are doesnt matter as long as you can get them. github\azure repos\bitbucket\etc all work fine

Comment: Aye, I didn't think that would be the real snag in this... Is there another step in the DevOps chain needed in order for the KuduScript template or the entrypoint.py processes to kick off after the files are published? When using the VsCode method the (onyx???, can't remember proper name) process automatically begins.

Comment: i think you need to use regular `publish to azure web app` step for it to do all the necessary things

Comment: Aye, that’s what the blog article in the answer ends up showing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, it's easy when know what to google for

http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7667

> To instruct the new Oryx build that I need it’s help I’m going to set
>   an app setting of name SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true. When
>   the runtime of the App Services app is set to Python, Oryx will then
>   run the “pip install -r requirements.txt” command for me.